# Javascript - concat string does not work as expected

Tags: javascript, string

What's the wrong with this Javascript line?

```
user: h.reem
domain: somedomain

var target = "//account/win/winlogin.aspx" + 
             "?username=" + 
             user.toString() + 
             "&domain=" + 
             domain.toString();
```

the resutl is always:

> //account/win/winlogin.aspx?username=h.reem

Any idea!!

[image]

Comment: Not for me: http://jsfiddle.net/92R99/1/ . What are `user` and `domain`?  properties of an object? Are they strings? Show us the definition of those.

Comment: why don't you try using `domain` and `user` instead of `domain.toString` and `user.toString` ?
As I feel that domain and user are strings!

Comment: your jsfiddle alerts '//account/win/winlogin.aspx?username=h.reem&domain=somedomain' here

Comment: @Matt: These values (user) & (domain) are coming from ActiveX. When I wrote them as you wrote (hard codded) then it worked well, but in my case it does not work!

Comment: @French: You might want to update your question and say that ;)... It's quite crucial! I've never used ActiveX, so can't help you any further I'm sorry... but someone else will be able to!

Comment: @ Matt: The problem is that the returned value fomr ActiveX is String !!

Comment: I edited the question and added a screen-shot

Comment: Does `alert(user+"X")` end in an `X`, if not what is `alert(user.charCodeAt(user.length-1))`

Comment: @downvoter: I wonder why down voting? my case is really weird for me at least.

Comment: @Alex K: `alert(user + "X")` shows only `h.reem` which is the value that in `user`. `user` isn't able to contact with anything after

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> alert(user + "X") shows only h.reem

The ActiveX component is probably returning a null terminated string (I've seen this with Scripting.TypeLib & a couple of the AD objects for example) so concatenating it with another string fails. (You can verify this if `0 === user.charCodeAt(user.length - 1)`).

You will need remove the last character before using the string;

`user = user.substr(0, user.length - 1);`

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
var sUser = user.toString();
var sDomain = domain.toString();

var target = "//account/win/winlogin.aspx" + "?username=" + sUser + "&domain=" + sDomain;
```

The above might not fix your problem but it should expose it - Could be that your user.toString() method isn't returning a string and is short-circuiting things...  If this doesn't answer your question I'd be glad to assist further, but it would be helpful if you posted the implementation or source of "user" somewhere ...

Comment: Thanks for your answer. It doesn't work. I added a screen-shot from my code. Kindly see it.